# Is it possible to use one laptop only as system tower for another laptop?

Tags: laptop, remote-desktop

I need to work on Laptop 1 [17" Lenovo | Linux Mint 20.3], using it only as monitor and keyboard, and the OS using Laptop 2 [13" HP | Windows 10].

Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Barrier](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier) if you want to use both at the same time:

- Barrier is software that mimics the functionality of a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch), which historically would allow you to use a single keyboard and mouse to control multiple computers by physically turning a dial on the box to switch the machine you're controlling at any given moment. Barrier does this in software, allowing you to tell it which machine to control by moving your mouse to the edge of the screen, or by using a keypress to switch focus to a different system.

Another option is to use VNC software [RealVNC], allowing you to connect to the other computer and control it as if you are working on it, which looks a bit like: [image: Screenshot]

These require both laptops to be powered on; you can't simply use a laptop screen for a different machine because laptops do not have video input, only output.

- A decent external keyboard would be much nicer to work with than a laptop keyboard.